# WordPress protected page with menu button and own login

Tags: php, wordpress, protected

I have a big issue and would like to ask you for help.

I've migrated my Minecraft server's website under WordPress administration. Before I moved it under Wordpress it had login page to access GUI which contained few thing for communicating between website & server by rcon.

I need to use own login which will create session. When session will be created I need to add one button into menu + let access logged user to my GUI. (I need have GUI like normal WP page with menu etc.)

Is there any way how to do that?

Here it is: http://www.pvpcraft.cz

Thank you,
David

Comment: yes, there is a way to do that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: what's wrong on my question? btw. I already searched for it.

Comment: you ask "is there any way how to do that" ... answer YES there is any way on how to do that.. where ist your specific question? your intention is clear, but it involves many topics and as such is hard to explain, and so, this is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.